# SQL to TRANSPOSE / PIVOT data from rows to columns for multiple rows of text per ID

Tags: sql, text, pivot, row, transpose

I want to provide a list of approver names in different columns by approval level, there are multiple approvers per cost centre - for this one cost centre the result should have 4 rows, as there are multiple rows per cost centre I cannot use MAX / MIN etc.

My SQL is:-

```
select rv.dim_value cost_centre,
(CASE when L1.role_id  like 'W-APP-L1-'+rv.dim_value Then L1.description else null end) AS L1_Approver,
(CASE when L1.role_id  like '%L2%' Then L1.description else null end) AS L2_Approver,
(CASE when L1.role_id  like '%L3%' Then L1.description else null end) AS L3_Approver,
(CASE when L1.role_id  like '%L4%' Then L1.description else null end) AS L4_Approver,
(CASE when L1.role_id  like '%L5%' Then L1.description else null end) AS L5_Approver,
(CASE when L1.role_id  like '%L6%' Then L1.description else null end) AS L6_Approver
from agldimvalue rv
INNER JOIN aagviuserdetail L1 ON rv.dim_value=SUBSTRING(L1.role_id,10,3) and L1.role_id like 'W-APP-%' and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP between L1.date_from and L1.date_to and L1.client='BK' and L1.role_id!=''
INNER JOIN aaguser usr ON usr.user_id=L1.user_id and usr.status='N'
where
rv.client='BK' and rv.attribute_id='C1' and rv.status='N' and rv.dim_value='AA1'
order by rv.dim_value ;
```

My result is:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qE1H.png)

The result is correct but I only want to show 4 rows for the AA1 cost centre, removing the nulls except in the columns where there are less than four approvers.

Comment: These [examples](https://dbfiddle.uk/OlK7Y_A3) should help.

Comment: @PonderStibbons  - thank you very much for the prompt reply!! That has given me exactly what I need.